# What is the proper way to use the same merge module in an MSI multiple times?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation, merge-module

I am creating a windows installer script and I have two features to be installed in their own folder.

I want to execute a merge module to BOTH of these folders. However, Windows Installer only allow a single copy of the merge module so I can only install it for one the application folder.

Is it possible to do this and if not, is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Merge modules are troublesome, better to use prerequisites delivered as separate MSI files. What merge module are you referring to?

Comment: Merge modules allow delivering a single MSI to install the product. With prerequisites in separate MSIs, you need to use a bootstrapper, and your installation stops to be a single install trasaction.

Answer (score 1):

Merge module can't be imported into a single MSI twice.

A better approach is to install the merge module components into one shared folder, and both your components will use it from there.

Another option is to add `CopyFile` elements and copy everything the merge module installs into the folder of your 2nd component. Yet I'd suggest using *shared folder*. Why do you need to duplicate files? Later, after an update, the versions of the shared component could become different which can lead you to trouble.

Comment: I need duplicates because each feature (application of a suite) are in their own folder and each need the merge module files. The applications are .NET applications.

Comment: I'm experimenting with extracting the files from the merge module and including them twice in the installer (a copy for each application folder). Let's see where this goes...

Comment: I'm not experienced in .NET… Yet I programmed for Win32 for a long time. And I can't understand why these DLLs can't be shared from one folder by two applications (of a suite). The whole point of DLLs is to share code rather to duplicate it. (Yeah I know about the DLL hell but in this case you control all the three components and I can't see the reason why you need two copies.)